# hwo to print an invoice receipt using flutter with Imchine E-POS model AP02?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, printing

I'm working on a Flutter project and I need to print an invoice receipt using the Imchine E-POS model AP02. I've been searching for documentation or examples, but I couldn't find any specific information on how to achieve this.

I have already tried the following steps:

1.Configured the Imchine E-POS model AP02 device and connected it to my Flutter app. 
2.Explored the Flutter printing libraries like esc_pos_printer and blue_thermal_printer, but I'm unsure about how to integrate them with the Imchine E-POS model AP02.

I would appreciate any guidance or sample code that demonstrates how to print an invoice receipt using Flutter and the Imchine E-POS model AP02. Specifically, I'm looking for information on how to establish a connection with the printer, send the necessary commands or data to print the receipt, and handle any potential errors or exceptions.

 
**Thank you in advance for your help.**